# Property asking different amounts of constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, propertyinfo, bank

I've got a short question. I have a class `Bank` that needs to have a property with different amounts of constructors.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bank ing = new Bank("ing");
        int AccountNrName1 = ing.OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode");
        int AccountNrName2 = ing.OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode", Balance, Minimum);
}
```

The constructor "OpenAccount" has to return both cases (AccountNrName1, AccountNrName2). Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Bank
{
    private string name, lastname, housenumber, postalcode;
    private int openaccount;
    private int balance;
    private int min;

    public int OpenAccount(string Name, string LastName, string HouseNumber, string PostalCode, int Balance, int Min)
    {
        name = Name;
        lastname = LastName;
        housenumber = HouseNumber;
        postalcode = PostalCode;
        balance = Balance;
        min = Min;

        return openaccount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about [Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) what you currently have is a method.

Comment: What's your question? Also, OpenAccount is a Method, not a constructor

Comment: Those aren't constructors, they're functions - do you want functions or constructors?

Comment: Add another function with only 4 parameters. Or probably better, use default parameters

Comment: Do you mean a function with different amounts of parameters?

Comment: What are `AccountNrName1` and `AccountNrName2` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, my method needs to return the asked strings and integers.

Answer (score 0):

Methods can have optional parameters, but, you can also overload - so, while you seem to want a constructor (because you're creating objects, but, you could make it methods.. but you do need to make the object first then!):

potentially you could have 2 constructors to allow for those conditions :

```
public OpenAccount (String name, String LastName, String Housenumber, String Postcode)
{ do stuff }
public OpenAccount (String name, String LastName, String Housenumber, String Postcode, int balance, int min)
{ do stuff }
```

Or you could do

```
public OpenAccount (String name, String LastName, String Housenumber, String Postcode, int balance=0, int min=0)
{do stuff}
```

which allows your to auto set those values if none are provided. I didnt check it works for constructors, but it should.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class to hold on to the account information.

```
public class Account {

    public Account(int accountNumber) { AccountNumber = accountNumber; }

    public int AccountNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get;set; } 
    public string LastName { get;set; } 
    public string HouseNumber { get;set; }
    public string PostalCode { get;set; }
    public int Balance { get;set; }
    public int Min { get;set; }
}
```

The `Bank` will hold a collection of Accounts and allow you to open accounts

```
public class Bank {

    string name;
    int accountIds = 0;
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    public Bank(string bankName) {
        name = bankName;
    }

    //Open an account and return the account number
    //Using optional parameters to allow
    //OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode");
    //OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode", Balance, Minimum);
    public Account OpenAccount(string Name, string LastName, string HouseNumber, string PostalCode, int Balance = 0, int Min = 0) {
        var newAccount = new Account(++accountIds) {
            Name = Name;
            LastName = LastName;
            HouseNumber = HouseNumber;
            PostalCode = PostalCode;
            Balance = Balance;
            Min = Min;
        };
        accounts.Add(newAccount);
        return newAccount;    
    }
}
```

So now when you call the Bank to open an Account

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Bank ing = new Bank("ing");
        Account AccountNrName1 = ing.OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode");
        Account AccountNrName2 = ing.OpenAccount("Name", "LastName", "HouseNumber", "PostalCode", Balance, Minimum);
    }
}
```

You should get back the opened account with all the properties populated.